# How to save and restore an interface on my fragment using onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, fragment, parcelable, serializable

when my fragment reload I need to recover the variables. All other variables are working except my callback.

I have a Fragment like this:

public class ClosetFragment extends Fragment {

```
private String [] closetSessions = null;
private DBName dbName = null;
private String token = null;
private RefreshCallback callback= null;

public ClosetFragment(String [] closetSessions, DBName dbName, String token, RefreshCallback callback){
    this.closetSessions = closetSessions;
    this.dbName = dbName;
    this.token = token;
    this.callback = callback;

}
public ClosetFragment(){

}

  @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("closetSessions", (Serializable) this.closetSessions);
        outState.putSerializable("dbName", (Serializable) this.dbName);
        outState.putSerializable("token", (Serializable) this.token);
        outState.putSerializable("callback", (Serializable) this.callback);
    }
```

And my callback is:

```
public interface RefreshCallback extends Serializable{
     public void onNeedrefresh();
}
```

And the Exception I got is:

AppSectionsPagerAdapter is the class that implements my callback.

```
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = br.com.closet4share.app.adapters.AppSectionsPagerAdapter$1)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1627)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:135)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1102)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:378)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1627)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2535)
05-25 12:04:06.037: E/AndroidRuntime(10822):    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3151)
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

This is how I implement my callback:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        fragment = new ClosetFragment(i,closetSessions,dbName,token, new RefreshCallback(){

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onNeedrefresh() {
                AppSectionsPagerAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });
        mPageReferences.put(i, new WeakReference<Fragment>(fragment));

        return fragment;

    }
```

Comment: Can you edit in a sample how you are using instantiating this `callback`? E.g. the implementation in `AppSectionsPagerAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

The exception occurs because the anonymous inner class contains a member variable for the parent adapter - this is what you access via `AppSectionsPagerAdapter.this`, and the Adapter is not Serializable.

You can't persist a callback this way, and to be honest, you shouldn't even attempt to do so. Persist only the internal **data** of the Fragment, and set the callback separately in `getItem`.

Comment: but when the fragment pauses and resume it doesn't call getItem. And my reference to callback is lost. So if I would change this arhitecture how could I tell my adpter to notifyDataSetChanged from inside the the fagment? @vzsg

Answer (score 1):

In my activity I created the method:

```
public void refreshAdapter(){
        if (mAppSectionsPagerAdapter != null)
            mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and in my Fragment a call:

```
Closet closet = (Closet)getActivity();
            closet.refreshAdapter();
```

And no nned to save anything. Thanks @vzsg.

Comment: That works too. One thing to be wary of is that `getActivity()` might return null if the Fragment is detached, so you have to be careful with AsyncTasks that might outlive the Activity for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AddToDoFragment.OnToDoAddedListener {

    private ArrayList<String> todoItems;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        } else {
            todoItems = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("todoItemTag");//the tag must match what the variable was saved with
        }

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        ToDoListFragment listToDo = new ToDoListFragment();
        listToDo = (ToDoListFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.list_view_fragment);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);
        listToDo.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void OnToDoAdded(String newToDo) {
        todoItems.add(newToDo);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        oustate.putStringArrayList("todoItemTag", todoItems);//it would be advised to make the tags a static final String
    }
}
```

You will want to override the onSavedInstanceState method so that you know when the state needs to be saved. Then you will also need to update your onCreate method to check if the savedInstanceState is null. If it is null then the activity hasn't been initiated. This is the example for your MainActivity class, and you can go from there:

Comment: Hi, savedInstanceState is not null and even if I didn't check in this code, the activity has been initiate. The problem is how to save and restore my callback? How do I put it and retrieve it from  savedInstanceState?